# Why move preposition phrase into the middle of a sentence

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The <>and<> block corresponds to the use in English of the word ‘and’
> to combine, **into one**, two statements about conditions that at any
> given time may or may not hold.

> Source: The Open University

For me the sentence should be:

The <>and<> block corresponds to the use in English of the word ‘and’ to combine two statements about conditions that at any given time may or may not hold **into one**.

I can fully understand what the quote means. But I want to know why the quote written in that way, and what benefits it has, thus I can use the technique in my own writing.

Comment: Your rephrasing is in principle "syntactically valid" - but it's stylistically appalling, and would normally be avoided by careful writers, because of the large gap between the active verb ***to combine*** and the adverbial element ***into one*** that modifies it. That large gap makes the text much harder to parse - the reader could hardly be expected to remember the current relevant "active verb" until meeting the associated adverbial element, so he has to "backtrack" looking for a suitable prior referent after reaching the end of the sentence.

Comment: (Perhaps *this* is a context where the oft-maligned "pedantic rule" about [***never end a sentence with a preposition***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with#:~:text=No%20sentence%20should%20end%20in,he%20writes%20his%20next%20column.) should be applied.)

Comment: Your explanation is sensible. Do you have more information about how to write stylistically by the way used in the quote.  I don't think the quote is related to the "pedantic rule" though, as "into one" is a preposition phrase, not just a preposition.

Comment: I wouldn't want to get bogged down in terminological hair-splitting here, but my immediate reaction is it ***is*** more or less the same construction as my cited "pedantic rule" - which *in general* is discredited today (if it ever *had* any credibility). Just as for almost all contexts, "a noun phrase" is syntactically equivalent to "a noun", so "a preposition phrase" is syntactically equivalent to "a preposition". As for "more information about how to write stylistically by the way used in the quote" - I wouldn't necessarily bother. Just omit the superfluous "into one" completely.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you about this. Like, I feel "'And' combine two statements into one" is correct, while "'And' combine two statements into" isn't correct. And I think 'into one' is a necessary part of the quote, couldn't be omitted.

Comment: There are lots of written instances of the sequence [*used to combine two statements*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22used+to+combine+two+statements%22) in Google Books, but I don't see any that include the ***totally superfluous*** qualifier "into one". I can't think why you would you want to argue for it being "necessary" in the cited context - two of anything can only be combined into ***one*** in any normal context. Whatever - you asked for advice on "how to write [stylistically]", and I gave you some What you do with that advice is up to you, though.

Comment: (Note that the clause *combine two things* doesn't ***need*** to be followed by "into" anything. It's perfectly valid as it stands.)

Comment: I think you are right. But for the quote, it is trying to explaining something about programing. "into one" emphasizes that two independent conditions become one compound condition, and they are calculated together to determine the status of the compound condition. Consequently, I think it may be clearer by having "into one" here. I am not trying to prove you are wrong, but trying to resolve my doubt. Thank you for your teaching. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree fully with Fumble Fingers’s comment (except the relevance of placement of prepositions).

The general rule in English, which is so lightly inflected a language, is that modifiers and qualifiers be adjacent to what is being modified or qualified.

> The horse ate large small the apple

is just grammatically wrong. We cannot tell whether the horse is large or small or whether the apple is large or small.

That general rule is not absolute. In some cases, it contravenes another rule (such as the rules on sequence of types of adjectives). In other cases, such as adverbial phrases, the rules of grammar do allow for considerable flexibility of placement of modifiers. But the greater the separation, the harder it is for people to understand. At some point, separation of modifier and thing modified becomes ungrammatical, but well before that point, separation becomes awkward.

I agree, however, with your feeling that the sentence that you originally quote could have been better written. In fact, I do not know exactly what it means. I think it probably means

> The << and >> block corresponds to the use in English of the word “and” to combine, into one statement, two assertions that may or may not hold simultaneously.

The meaning may be clear in context, but the sentence itself is not clear.

**EDIT**: My answer above attempted to make two points.

First, why “in one” was placed where it was in the original sentence. The reason is that the phrase is applied to the infinitive “to combine,” and a general rule of English encourages putting modifiers close to what is being modified.

That point justifies the placement of “in one” in the quoted statement.

Second, if the original poster asked the question because he did not find the quoted sentence’s meaning clear, I agreed and tried to rewrite it in a way that might have expressed clearly what I guessed its intended meaning might be.

Based on the comment from the original poster below, it now appears that the context is truth values. I’d now rewrite the sentence in a completely different way.

> The >> and << block operates on statements like the English word “and.” It combines two statements into one that is deemed true only if both statements are true.

Comment: '<>and<> block' is a programming unit in a customized app for The Open University, for example '3 < 5 and 9 < 10' will report true to the program. The sentence want to inform in English the word 'and' has similar function, like I like you and him both.

Comment: @Linje See my edit above.

Comment: Your very first statement is probably important for many learners. I know for a fact that modern English is "very lightly inflected" compared to classical Latin & Greek, but I'm *guessing* it's also more lightly inflected that the native languages of many learners here.  So *sequence* (specifically, the placement of "words modifying other words") will often be more important in English than in the learner's native tongue. Plus there's also the matter of "ease of parsing", whereby *I like X and Y both* is obviously much harder to parse than *I like both X and Y* if X and/or Y are longish texts.